# Tree diagram Chain Rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let
$$
\begin{align}
w &= f(x,y,z)\\
z &= z(x,y)\\
x &= x(t)\\
y &= y(t)\\
\end{align}
$$
be differentiable functions.
Find the formula for the derivative of $w$ with respect to $t$.

My answer:
$w = f(x,y,z) \implies \dfrac{dw}{dt} = \dfrac{dw}{dx} \cdot \dfrac{dw}{dy} \cdot\dfrac{dw}{dz}$
$$
\begin{align}
z &= z(x,y) \\
x &= x(t) \\
y &= y(t) \\
\end{align}
\implies \frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dt}
$$
It is getting confusing to me. I used to make a tree diagram to make it a bit easier but this time, it is out of my reach. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

Note that
\begin{eqnarray*}
w\to \left\{\begin{aligned} \color{blue}{x \to x=(t)} \\ \color{red}{ y \to y=(t)} \\ \color{green}{ z \to z= z(x,y) \to \left\{\begin{aligned} \color{blue}{x\to x(t)} \\ \color{red}{y \to y(t)}\end{aligned} \right.} \\  \end{aligned}\right.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, by chain rule, you have
$$\frac{\partial w}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\color{blue}{\frac{dx}{dt}}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\color{red}{\frac{dy}{dt}}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\color{\green}{\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}}\color{blue}{\frac{dx}{dt}}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\color{\green}{\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}}\color{red}{\frac{dy}{dt}}$$